# include a special character (!,@,#,&) not include other special characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

i want to test the password field and will update the html for result.

One of them is:

**include a special character (!,@,#,&) not include other special characters**

i have test first condition like this

```
    reg=  new RegExp('(?=.*[!@#&])');
    var regexmatch=reg.test(password);
```

- can anyone tell me how to test this condition in one regex

Comment: What do you mean by `not include other special characters` ? Post some valid and invalid strings.

Comment: mean only this character allowed  [!@#&]

Comment: What all is allowed apart from `special characters`

Comment: @muhammad still unclear for me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?=.*[!@#&])(?!.*[^!@#&])
```

This should do it for you.The `negative lookahead` will not allow other special characters.

```
reg=  new RegExp('(?=.*[!@#&])(?!.*[^!@#$])');
var regexmatch=reg.test(password);
```

If alphanumerics is allowed

```
^(?=.*[!@#&])(?!.*[^!@#&a-zA-Z0-9\n])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#&]+$
```

Try this.See demo.It will allow only `alphanumerics` and `!@#&`.

https://regex101.com/r/eS7gD7/32

Comment: no its return true on this input  !@#$# its is giving false when i press $ but when again i press # its return true

Comment: the last one is work for me it does not allow you !@#$#

Comment: not by me maybe some else who have answer but i have accept your answer. i have accept your answer bcz its works perfect for me.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, you mean this:

```
/^[a-z\d!@#&]+$/i
```

This only allows letters, numbers and the 4 symbols.